# Factor Analysis R - different results?

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I've run a factor analysis on a dataset in R, using the psych package. Up until about 1 month ago, it has spit out the same output, but recently, it's different.

When I try running it on older versions of the psych package, it also churns out a different output. I'm at a loss for diagnosing this issue and trying to get the original output. I don't see how it could be a coding issue since the results were generated in the past -- I'm just struggling getting the same output now..

Below is the condensed version of code.

To download psych package:

```
# check if package "psych" is installed. if not, remind the user to install
if(("psych" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) == FALSE){
  stop("Please install package 'psych' by running 'install.package('psych')'")
}
library(psych)  # this package is needed for factor analysis
```

To run the FA:

```
n_factor=3


# the variables defined below are used to record the iterative process
LIST_min_in_max_loading_vector <- NULL
LIST_drop_variable <- NULL

min_in_max_loading_vector=0
flag=1
while(TRUE){
  cat("The ",flag," Step is done. \n")
  fa_result<- fa(dat,nfactors=n_factor,rotate = "varimax", cor='poly')
  max_loading_in_each_row <- sapply(1:dim(fa_result$loadings)[1],function(j) max(abs(fa_result$loadings[j,])))
  variable_names=row.names(fa_result$loadings)

  min_in_max_loading_vector <- min(max_loading_in_each_row)

  # Please note that here we have a cut-off value 0.5. 
  # This means that the minimum of the absolute values of all the loadings must be bigger than 0.5
  # it's also the stop condition of our iterative algorithm
  if(min_in_max_loading_vector>0.5){
    break
  }
  min_variable <- variable_names[which(max_loading_in_each_row==min_in_max_loading_vector)]

  cat("The minimum of the maximum absolute loadings is:",min_in_max_loading_vector,"\n")
  drop_index <- which(row.names(fa_result$loadings)==min_variable) 
  cat(min_variable," is droped in this round.\n\n")
  dat <- dat[,-drop_index]

  #record the process of dropping
  LIST_min_in_max_loading_vector[flag]=min_in_max_loading_vector
  LIST_drop_variable[flag] <- min_variable

  print(fa_result$loadings)

  flag=flag+1
}
```

Can anyone potentially troubleshoot this?

Comment: You need to do some leg work on your own here.  Are you certain that the exact same input data is being used?  If not, how has the data changed?  Are you certain that the code is identical?  Have you tried running your script one line at a time until you notice something fishy?

Comment: Hi Tim, the exact same data is being used and there should be no changes . And, I’m certain the code is identical since I haven’t touched it since the last run. The one line at a time run works until the factor analysis which is essentially a loop. I’m just wondering if there is a possibility that the packages change and so the functions are different ?